# Reliable Way To Cancel ItemCheck Event On CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Does anyone know of a reliable way to cancel the ItemCheck event on a CheckedListBox? I am in a situation where the ItemCheck event should basically discard changes on a form, however, if the person decides to cancel the discard I would like the ItemCheck event not to fire so as not to change anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is easy to do with the ItemCheck event.  Just set the value back.  Like this:

```
    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        if (someCondition) e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
        else {
            // Regular stuff
            //...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void cancelevent()       
{           
  checkedListBox1.ItemCheck -= new   ItemCheckEventHandler(this.checkedListBox1_ItemCheck);           
}
```

Call this method any where to cancel the event.

If we += the event will be created and -= will remove the event.

If you want more details please mention. :)