# How To Disable Check/Uncheck Of An Item In A CheckedListBox In C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a `CheckedListBox` with 10 items. On each item check a method is being called. I want to disable the checkbox of that particular item for which the method is being executed so that user cannot uncheck the item till the job is completed.

**Note:** Unchecking of an item calls another method.

Here is the code of `ItemCheck` Event:

```cs
private void host_listbox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.Index;
    
    try
    {
        string sitem = host_listbox.Items[index].ToString();
        host_list[sitem].checked_event=e;
        if (!host_list[sitem].is_busy)
        {
            host_config.listEnabled = false;
            host_list[sitem].con_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            
        }
        if (host_listbox.GetItemCheckState(index) == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            host_list[sitem].connected = false;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        output_textbox.AppendText("connection failed!" +ex.ToString() +Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about disabling the CheckedListBox control until the other method is finished?

Comment: no i cant do that. There are multiple items and i am making their "itemCheck" event work in a background worker.

Answer (score 1):

You can check/uncheck items in your checkedListBox with this code

```
checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(item, true);
```

for more informations go to [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection.aspx)

Comment: no i want to disable the checkbox of that item till the job is executed or atleast prevent any uncheck event on that particular item

Comment: you can use the checkedListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None or simple disable this control

Answer (score 1):

```
  private void host_listbox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
  {

      int index = e.Index;
      try
      {
          string sitem = host_listbox.Items[index].ToString();
          if (host_list[sitem].is_busy // or whatever indicates that background worker is running or any condition that specifies, that you do not want to let this item to be changed)
              e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue; //Change the value back
          else
          { 
          //Let the checked state of the item change
```

Comment: did not get what you meant in the else part

Comment: What is important is the line e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue; Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455443/reliable-way-to-cancel-itemcheck-event-on-checkedlistbox

Answer (score 0):

This code prevent checked state change if associated background work is running:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        workerList = new List<BackgroundWorker>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var el = new BackgroundWorker();
            el.DoWork += (s, e) =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            };

            workerList.Add(el);
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add("el " + i);
        }
    }

    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = workerList[e.Index];

        if (worker.IsBusy)
        {
            e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public List<BackgroundWorker> workerList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think, that only funcion solution is set selection mode

```
CheckedListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
  if (busy)
    e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you can explain the code as well instead of just adding the code.